# Error rebuilding ATMHud.DLL for Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, atmhud

After updating to the latest versions of Xamarin Studio this morning the ZBar and ATMHud references in our project started throwing a bunch of errors, all of which were:

The type 'MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.  Consider adding a reference to assembly 'monotouch, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' (CS0012)'

I did some reading and found out that I needed to rebuild both of the libraries because of something to do with "assembly strong names" in Xamarin.  I was able to muddle my way through rebuilding the ZBar library, but the ATMHud rebuild has given me some trouble and I'm not familiar enough with what I'm doing to fix the problem.

I downloaded the ATMHud project from github and followed the instructions in the readme which state "Run 'make' in the binding directory to build ATMHud.dll", but when I do that I get errors.

Teds-Mac:binding ted$ make

/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/bin/btouch -e atmhud.cs enums.cs AssemblyInfo.cs --out=ATMHud.dll --link-with=libATMHudSDK.a,libATMHudSDK.a
/var/folders/75/vl_6zkyx03sc4tymnp41lsgw0000gn/T/09x9yx7m.nz9/AtmHud/AtmHud.g.cs(751,86): error CS0103: The name `class_ptr' does not exist in the current context
/var/folders/75/vl_6zkyx03sc4tymnp41lsgw0000gn/T/09x9yx7m.nz9/AtmHud/AtmSoundFX.g.cs(75,104): error CS0103: The name`class_ptr' does not exist in the current context

Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings

btouch: API binding contains errors.

make: *** [ATMHud.dll] Error 1

I've scanned through the files in the folders but can't seem to track down any references to "class_ptr".

Can anyone help with what might be the cause of the problem I'm seeing, and can you confirm that this will get me past the original "assembly strong names" problem I'm seeing?

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary measure you can fix your old assemblies with this tool: https://github.com/rolfbjarne/iOSRefUpdater

**Update**

I've fixed the ATMHud bindings, now they should compile with newer versions of Xamarin.iOS installed as well.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I appreciate the quick reply