# Unable to compile TestFlight dll with bindings for monotouch

Tags: binding, xamarin.ios, testflight

I'm trying to make the [TestFlight binding for monotouch DLL](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/TestFlight) without succeeding. The bindings are made for TestFlight SDK 1.2.1, but the only available versions from TestFlight are 1.2.5 and 1.2.6. So I tried the [pull request #125 version](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/pull/125) which should work with 1.2.5 and 1.2.6. However, I get the same errors:

```
/var/folders/ ... /TestFlight/TestFlight.g.cs(89,69): error CS0103: The name `class_ptr' does not exist in the current context
/var/folders/ ... /TestFlight/TestFlight.g.cs(103,62): error CS0103: The name `class_ptr' does not exist in the current context
/var/folders/ ... /TestFlight/TestFlight.g.cs(114,62): error CS0103: The name `class_ptr' does not exist in the current context
/var/folders/ ... /TestFlight/TestFlight.g.cs(125,62): error CS0103: The name `class_ptr' does not exist in the current context
/var/folders/ ... /TestFlight/TestFlight.g.cs(134,55): error CS0103: The name `class_ptr' does not exist in the current context
/var/folders/ ... /TestFlight/TestFlight.g.cs(145,62): error CS0103: The name `class_ptr' does not exist in the current context
/var/folders/ ... /TestFlight/TestFlight.g.cs(158,62): error CS0103: The name `class_ptr' does not exist in the current context
```

These seven errors correspond to the seven abstract methods in the interface, but I don't know that to do with that information.

I had a look at the [iOSRegUpdater](https://github.com/rolfbjarne/iOSRefUpdater) posted in [the only similar SO question I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108874/error-rebuilding-atmhud-dll-for-monotouch), but it only solves the issue if you already have a DLL (which is what I fail to make).

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this commit too: [9dc256b8](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/commit/9dc256b8640a6fd35ce3872df886206abe22e2d8)

Comment: Hi Rolf, I couldn't get it to build, until I realised that you need to download the Testflight SDK ZIP FILE FIRST, then add it to the BINDING folder in monotouch-bindings-master/testflight/binding.....AND THEN rename the testflight sdk zip file to the same version that the make file is trying to run (currently 1.2.1) - despite the testflight sdk being on version 2.0. Might be helpful for future users if these steps are explicitly stated on the GitHub readme.

Answer (score 2):

I've re-written the ReadMe for the Monotouch Testflight bindings on GitHub, because it took me three hours to make this work, as the setup explanation was missing a few vital steps...

## TestFlight

1) This is a MonoTouch binding for the TestFlight SDK which can be found at
***DOWNLOAD THIS FIRST*** - https://testflightapp.com/sdk/

2) Download the monotouch bindings zip file. It is huge.

3) Navigate to monotouch-bindings-master/testflight/binding & copy the testflight SDK ZIP file (do not unzip it), to this directory.

4) IMPORTANT - The make file in this monotouch-bindings-master/testflight/binding directory is setup to target a particular named version of the testflight SDK zip file. When I ran it, it was searching for "TestFlightSDK1.2.1.zip". HOWEVER, the version of the TestFlight SDK zip file that I downloaded was named "TestFlightSDK2.0.0.zip". Thus, you need to rename your zip file to "TestFlightSDK1.2.1.zip".

4) Open terminal, navigate to monotouch-bindings-master/testflight/binding. Run MAKE (just type MAKE into the terminal).

5) Once this has built, you will see two files that you need in the binding directory. "testflightlib.a" and "TestFlight.dll".

6) Copy both of these to the root of your Monotouch project.

7) Open your project in the Xamarin IDE and add a new reference to the TestFlight.dll.

8) Start using the methods in the dll - You will need to get your AppToken from the TestFlight page after you have setup an app on testflightapp.com.

9) Run the TestFlight.TakeOff method to initialize TestFlight in your app. To use the thread safe TakeOff method. Change TestFlight.TakeOff(token) to TestFlight.TakeOffThreadSafe(token)

10) You can then use the other methods such as TestFlight.PassCheckpoint, Testflight.OpenFeedback etc. (as shown on the sample project in the monotouch-binding TestFlight sample project.

Happy testing.....That was an absolute mission!

Simon - www.segnoapp.com

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write-up.  I only needed to copy TestFlight.dll to my project.  I didn't need testflightlib.a.

Comment: Of course having spent some time actually using TestFlight, I now realise that it's terrible.

Comment: Could you please provide some examples to back that up?  The only minor thing I've encountered along those lines is that their logging statement is now synchronous, resulting in some unexpected performance issues.